# List down duplicate files from a list in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to list down all files with similar name into separate folder but can't figure out there names to move them.
From below i am creating folder with Duplicate name in my Working directory and then passing all files through split function to get middle part of name from `xmlName = xml.split('.')[1]` line. Now `xmlName` has only part of file name which helps me me to decided duplicate name.

Below is the list of file in working directory:

```
# ls
CRON.JC_ADA_SOURCE_DLOAD.xml            Duplicate                                   TERA.SC_CACHE_PURGE_01.xml
CRON.JC_ADA_SOURCE_WLOAD.xml            POWE.BI_RUN_INFO_WKFLW_INF1.xml  test.py
CRON.SC_ADA_CLEANUP_SCRIPT.xml          POWE.JC_ADA_SOURCE_DLOAD.xml            Unknown
CRON.SC_CACHE_PURGE_01.xml              POWE.SC_CHECK_ADA_DATA_FILE_INF2.xml
#
```

Below is the code (Where i am not sure how to list down only duplicate files).

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, sys

Working_Dir = "/home/export/Partition/JobDefinition"

if not os.path.exists('./Duplicate'):
    os.makedirs('./Duplicate', 0755)

for path, dir, files in os.walk(Working_Dir):
    for xml in files:
        xmlName = xml.split('.')[1]
        if xmlName == xmlName:
            print xmlName
```

Output:

```
# python test.py
SC_ADA_CLEANUP_SCRIPT
SC_CHECK_ADA_DATA_FILE_INF2
JC_ADA_SOURCE_WLOAD
BI_RUN_INFO_WKFLW_INF1
JC_ADA_SOURCE_DLOAD
SC_CACHE_PURGE_01
JC_ADA_SOURCE_DLOAD
SC_CACHE_PURGE_01
py
#
```

What output i need is below names so that i can move respective file to Duplicate folder:

```
JC_ADA_SOURCE_DLOAD
SC_CACHE_PURGE_01
```

Answer (score 1):

**The Lazy Answer**

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) will do what you want, by magic.

```
import collections

c = collections.Counter([])

for path, dir, files in os.walk(Working_Dir):
    c += collections.Counter([xml.split('.')[1] for xml in files])
```

**The Somewhat Less Lazy Answer**

Keep track of every unique file with `set`

```
seen = set()
duplicates = set()
for path, dir, files in os.walk(Working_Dir):
    for xml in files:
        xmlName = xml.split('.')[1]
        if xmlName in seen:
            duplicates.add(xmlName)
        seen.add(xmlName)
```

Comment: Thanks for providing code. I was trying to go with less Lazy Answer but below is the error. I am really very new to Python.
seen.add(xmlName)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'add'

Comment: Thanks for the modification. I tried to print duplicates variable and below is the output: How to move only those two files to Duplicate folder ?
`# python test.py
set([])
set([])
set([])
set([])
set([])
set([])
set(['JC_ADA_SOURCE_DLOAD'])
set(['SC_CACHE_PURGE_01', 'JC_ADA_SOURCE_DLOAD'])
set(['SC_CACHE_PURGE_01', 'JC_ADA_SOURCE_DLOAD'])`

Answer (score 0):

If you only want duplicates, you can store names as you find them in something (set would be most appropriate, but a list will do); if something you are about to put in is already there, it is a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for guiding Scott. I am very new to Python and therefore not sure how to use set but now since i know that set has to be used, i will find its usage.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find the duplicate elements in your list and create an other list for only those duplicate elements this is how you can do it:

Here I have list `a` with two duplicate elements in it `2` and `3`. I find those elements in `list a` and create an other list `b` which will contain only those two elements.

```
import collections
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,]
b = [item for item, count in collections.Counter(a).items() if count > 1]
```

When you print `b` the output is:

```
[2, 3]
```

Then, later if you also want to remove the duplicate elements from `a`, you can use `set` to do it like this:

```
a = set([1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,])
```

Now when you print `a` the output is:

```
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```